# Implicit declaration of function found in header?

Tags: c, header-files

I have the following in my file.h:

```
#define SetSP(sp)  asm("movq  %0,%%rsp":           : "r" (sp)  )
```

However, in my file.c file, when I try using it for example:

```
SetSp(lwp_ptable[lwp_procs].sp);
```

I get an implicit declaration of function SetSp, when I compile file.c. I have #include "file.h" in file.c. Thoughts?

Comment: Did you have included the header file?

Comment: Yes, I do include file.h

Comment: Did you put an extra space just after the `#define SetSP` and before `(sp)` ? Did you include your `file.h` in `file.c` ? Use `gcc -C -E file.c > file.i` then look inside `file.i` to understand what the preprocessor is doing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your define is `SetSP`, while you use it as `SetSp`, note the case difference in letter `p`. Welcome to case sensitive language...

Answer (score 1):

If you've copied and pasted your code, note that `SetSP` is not the same as `SetSp` (you've used a lower case p when you invoked the macro).